# Modify size (reduce) Material UI SVG - svg.MuiSvgIcon-root

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to know if it possible to modify the "container" of the SVG.

I think that that "container" is actually the SVG itself, so if I modify (reduce) it, also the arrow will shrink.

I know how to modify the size of an SVG, but what I need is to reduce the "container" size while keeping the same size of the blue arrow.

I tried:

```
 <ArrowDropUpIcon className={classes.arrowIcon} />
```

where:
`arrowIcon: {width: 10, height: 10}`

**BUT** this shrinks the icon (see second photo)

[image: "container SVG"]
[image: "second photo]

Answer (score 0):

Customizing viewBox props is the solution to scale the svg.

`<ArrowDropUpIcon viewBox="5 3 20 20" className={classes.arrowIcon} />` this is just for reference

For example, if the SVG element is 500 (width) by 200 (height), and you pass viewBox="0 0 50 20", this means that the coordinates inside the SVG will go from the top left corner (0,0) to bottom right (50,20) and each unit will be worth 10px.

Source: [Official Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/)

References:
1.[MDN Docs about SVG viewBox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)
2. [An article about how to scale svg](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)